# R - Looping over a list of metrics on a user defined model

Tags: r, regression

I currently have a difference in difference model and would like to measure different metrics for the same model in an efficient manner.

For example, I have a data frame with columns for Miles Driven, Hours Worked, State, Group, Time.

Currently, have code where I copy and paste the model for each metric:

```
# Create DID models
model_miles <- lm(df$miles_driven ~ df$Group 
                    + df$Time 
                    + df$Group * df$Time, data = df)
model_hours <- lm(df$hours_worked ~ df$Group 
       + df$Time 
       + df$Group * df$Time, data = df)

# Select results using clustered standard errors. The purpose of this is to 
# avoid making distributional assumptions about the errors in the models. 
results_miles <- clubSandwich::coef_test(model_miles, 
                                        vcov = "CR2", 
                                        cluster = df$state, 
                                        test = "Satterthwaite")
results_hours <- clubSandwich::coef_test(model_hours, 
                           vcov = "CR2", 
                           cluster = df$state, 
                           test = "Satterthwaite")

 results <- data.table::rbindlist(list(results_miles, results_hours))
View(results)
```

I would like to somehow create a list of my metric names, and loop over this list using a user defined function, in order to make this process faster and more automated, but I haven't been able to get this to work correctly:

```
#list of metrics
metrics <- c("miles_driven", "hours_worked")

udf <- function(metric, dataframe){
 # Create DID model
 model <- lm(dataframe$metric ~ df$Group 
            + dataframe$Time 
            + dataframe$Group * df$Time, data = dataframe)

 # Select results using clustered standard errors. The purpose of this 
 is to 
 # avoid making distributional assumptions about the errors in the 
 models. 
 results_miles <- clubSandwich::coef_test(model_miles, 
                                   vcov = "CR2", 
                                   cluster = dataframe$state, 
                                   test = "Satterthwaite")[4,]
 View(results)
}

lapply(metrics, udf)
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you use `[[` instead of `$`.

For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(A=1:1, B=1:2)
x <- "A"
lm(dat[[x]] ~ dat$B)
```

You can do more advanced things of this sort in loops by using `get` and `assign`.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations I always `glue` a formula together in `lm`. Example below. You can just give the variable names if you've supplied `lm` with `data` argument, rather than explicitly passing `dataframe$varname`.

```
library(glue)
dostuff <- function(metric, dataframe){
  model.form <- '{metric} ~ b + c + c*d'
  lm(as.formula(glue(model.form)), data = dataframe)
}

df <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = runif(10), c = runif(10), d = runif(10))

dostuff('a', df)
```

If you want to stick to base R, the two objects below are equal

```
glue('{metric} ~ b + c + c*d')
paste(metric, '~ b + c + c*d')
```